# How can I lookup a value based on user input and and use display it to the user in django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently learning to develop websites using Django. I have the following problem, where I have two models:

```
class  Model_1(models.Model):
   id = models.Charfield(max_length=250)
   account_name = models.Foreignkey(Accounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Model_2(models.Model:
   account_name = models.Charfield(250)
   account_type = models.Charfield(250)
```

I have a html form where the user inputs their id, and chooses the account name. I would like that to redirect them to a new html page where they can see the account type that is associated with that account name. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What if there are multiple `Model_2`s for the given `account_name`?

Comment: There can only be one Model_2 for each account_name, since the account_name is unique.

Comment: but in your model it is not unique at all...